# MongoDB C# Driver tailable cursor on oplog.rs

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I am trying to write an oplog watcher using the MongoDB C# Driver that resembles the one implemented in Java [Here](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-java-driver/blob/master/examples/ReadOplog.java).

So far i've managed to write:

```
public static void Read()
{
    const string connectionString = "mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017,127.0.0.1:27018/?replicaSet=rs0";
    MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(connectionString);

    MongoDatabase local = mongoClient.GetServer().GetDatabase("local");
    MongoCollection opLog = local.GetCollection("oplog.$main");
    BsonValue lastId = BsonMinKey.Value;
    while (true)
    {
        var query = Query.GT("_id", lastId);
        var cursor = opLog.FindAs<BsonDocument>(query)
                    .SetFlags(
                        QueryFlags.AwaitData |
                        QueryFlags.TailableCursor |
                        QueryFlags.NoCursorTimeout)
                    .SetSortOrder(SortBy.Ascending("$natural"));
        using (var enumerator = (MongoCursorEnumerator<BsonDocument>)cursor.GetEnumerator())
        {
            while (true)
            {
            // I get a "tailable cursor requested on non capped collection" Exception
                if (enumerator.MoveNext())
                {
                    var document = enumerator.Current;
                    lastId = document["_id"];
                }
                else
                {
                    if (enumerator.IsDead)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                    if (!enumerator.IsServerAwaitCapable)
                    {
                        Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've created the oplog on the server and succesfully queried it from the mongo command line using the instructions found [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/change-oplog-size/), but i cant figure out why the exception says it is not capped.

Comment: I have already looked over [this c# implementation](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!searchin/mongodb-user/tailable$20cursor/mongodb-user/vpuXq-FMfFQ/UT6Z3O2DVj8J) but it creates a new capped collection, and im more interested in the oplog.rs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using and have set up a replicaset, you have an oplog.

To query the oplog, you would use the database 'local' as you do.

then change

```
local.GetCollection("oplog.$main");
```

to

```
local.GetCollection("oplog.rs");
```

Comment: Thank You for the suggestion, it solved the problem. I am curios though if you could explain what exactly was the point of the "oplog.$main" in the linked example? Does the file get created if a replicaSet is not enabled?

Comment: Not sure about the name "oplog.$main". It might be legacy from older mongod naming. As far as oplog, it is created for replication and not if no replica set is created. You might have heard of journal files, but they are not oplog - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8970739/how-the-jounal-file-and-oplog-files-are-different-from-each-other-in-mongodb

Comment: Ok, thank you for the extra information. Indeed, i am interested in the oplog and not the journal files.